# GetPrivateProfileString can not read network file details

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, ini

My MFC C++ application is using the following code to fetch details from INI file.

```
GetPrivateProfileString("MyDefaults", "MyCompanyID", " ", szBuffer, 5000,csConfIniName);
```

When I provide a local path (Eg: `C\Temp\Myfile.ini`) to `csConfIniName`, it can fetch the `MyCompanyID` value. But when I give a network path eg. `\\10.1.1.500\c$\Development\Myfile.ini`, `GetPrivateProfileString` fills `szBuffer` with a blank value.

Any suggestion?

Comment: First guess is you're forgetting that backslashes need to be escaped in C++ string literals (e.g. `"\\10.1.1.500\\c$\\..."`). Otherwise, check for failure and see what the error code is.

Comment: Also, try to access the file using another method. It'll probably fail too, indicating the problem isn't GetPrivateProfileString-specific. You can use Process Monitor to see what file are you actually trying to access. Lastly, there might be a permissions and mapping difference between the app and your user if, say, the app is run as a service or as administrator.

Comment: Read the docs for `GetPrivateProfileString`. They advise you not to use the function. Heed the advice. Use a bespoke pure C++ library for accessing INI files. Code will be better. And you'll avoid all the compat hacks and perf issues with `GetPrivateProfileString`.

Comment: my guess is that the network names should start with two backslahes so try this  `"\\\\10.1.1.500\\c$\\Development\\Myfile.ini"`  or this `"\\.\\\\10.1.1.500\\c$\\Development\\Myfile.ini"`

Comment: I have tried all combinations and could not crack. My code is as given below:                                        CString inifileName ("\\\\devserver\\C$\\ABC\\MyIniFile.DAT");
 char* Output = new char[5000];
 ::GetPrivateProfileString("MyDefaults", "CID", " ", Output, 5000,inifileName);
 CString MyID = Output; // MyId is empty

 inifileName = "C:\\ABC\\MyIniFile.DAT";
 ::GetPrivateProfileString("MyDefaults", "CID", " ", Output, 5000,inifileName);
 MyID = Output; //MyID is "1d81e398-c3da-4a84-ab73-b177a619e5a3"

Comment: My Ini File is format is      [MyDefaults]
  CID=1e51e398-c3da-4b84-ab73-b177a61965a3

Comment: Also this is old C++ application in maintenance mode and the code someone wrote in VS2008